# Repeating pattern for typing TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript

I want to take unlimited arguments for a generic function which attaches valid keys together with `.`'s. This could technically take as many arguments as there are nested objects.

The following code snippet is working as is, but I was wondering if it could take any number of arguments rather than only ones I manually type out?

```js
const tt = <Lang>() => {
  return <
    A extends keyof Lang,
    B extends keyof Omit<Lang[A], keyof string>,
    C extends keyof Omit<Lang[A][B], keyof string>,
    D extends keyof Omit<Lang[A][B][C], keyof string>,
    E extends keyof Omit<Lang[A][B][C][D], keyof string>,
    F extends keyof Omit<Lang[A][B][C][D][E], keyof string>
    // Can this repeat without manually typing each out?
  >(
    a: A,
    b?: B,
    c?: C,
    d?: D,
    e?: E,
    f?: F,
  ) => {
    return [a, b, c, d, e, f].filter(Boolean).join('.');
  };
};

console.log(tt<{Parent: {child: 'child'}}>()('Parent', 'child'));
// Console: "Parent.child"
```

The code works as is, but it should be able to take unlimited arguments.

Maybe something like this:

```js
const tt = <Lang>() => {
  return <A extends SomethingGoesHere>(...args: A) => {
    return args.join('.');
  };
};

console.log(tt<{Parent: {child: 'child'}}>()('Parent', 'child'));
// Console: "Parent.child"
```

---

A follow up question: I hate that this has to be a higher-order function just to get the generic typing to work. Why doesn't typescript allow me to infer `A`-`F` based on the provided generic type `Lang`?

In an ideal world I'd be able to do this:

```js
const tt = <
  Lang,
  A extends keyof Lang,
  B extends keyof Omit<Lang[A], keyof string>,
  C extends keyof Omit<Lang[A][B], keyof string>,
  D extends keyof Omit<Lang[A][B][C], keyof string>,
  E extends keyof Omit<Lang[A][B][C][D], keyof string>,
  F extends keyof Omit<Lang[A][B][C][D][E], keyof string>
>(
  a: A,
  b?: B,
  c?: C,
  d?: D,
  e?: E,
  f?: F,
) => {
  return [a, b, c, d, e, f].filter(Boolean).join('.');
};

tt<{Parent: {child: 'child'}}>('Parent', 'child');
// ^ error: Expected 7 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)
```

But it throws that error.

Comment: The version you have is the best one we can do for now. You can't do it all in one check because TS does not have partial inference for functions. And while you can use tuples in rest parameters to capture an unlimited number of types, you can't really have them relate to each other like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TitianCernicova-Dragomir is right, there's nothing really better here (at least nothing [supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980)).  One thing that often works better than fighting with TypeScript's type system, is to refactor the code into something it understands better.

For example, what if instead of supporting a variadic function, you make a chainable function where each call narrows the current type `T` to be one of its properties `T[K]`?  Something like this:

```
type ObjStrKey<T> = T extends object ? Extract<keyof T, string> : never;

interface Keychain<T> {
  <K extends ObjStrKey<T>>(k: K): Keychain<T[K]>;
  value: string;
}

function keychain<T>(): Keychain<T> {
  function kc<T, K extends ObjStrKey<T>>(
    this: Keychain<T>,
    k: K
  ): Keychain<T[K]> {
    const value = (this.value ? this.value + "." : "") + k;
    const v = { value };
    return Object.assign(kc.bind(v), v);
  }
  const v = { value: "" };
  return Object.assign(kc.bind(v), v);
}
```

Which works like this:

```
interface Person {
  parent: Person;
  child: Person;
  spouse: Person;
  name: string;
}

const kcp = keychain<Person>();
console.log(kcp("child")("spouse")("child")("parent")("name").value);
// child.spouse.child.parent.name
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwMrAE4GkIgDwBUB8UAvFLlBAB7AQB2AJgM5QD2iEAxsFAPxQCiVVAENO2ANZZmAM1IAaKAzQBLGgHNCALig0IANwioA3AChjK6qikjomEOwAWQlXkIBvY1CjZ05KrUawiCgYWC74ABRiWugAlNFYDk40eADa6AC6+CaeukIANgCuEFqKqCqqJgC+plIFNJxKzDRQEnaOzgThcVC2iR1uHlC19cCNzWLsePI+lNT0TPDIaLZh4YOewPZKDPFtSS6y6y3Rg9297cm4aZlQ7p6e7E2KULmF0CThm9sAdK9FPFAvgxfvl-gBqKAAIm+kKgWkhkJiUAhYmy90eNGeumItxeoOglTRnlQEGABVQzUWHGA3yEDAYSlUNEi7G+cBUdHCuhi8m5aOqDyeXGxJFceLe8NhhMGJLJFMCCGptPpjOZEzZHK5PJeMSqpnMBis7GgAAUDAwmrdBmAhCSaMAtGbUBaaGiHEo8nRHeammiGGBmAUGMUoE6XWiaEIALYh0rlPXGDHPCZgHGtPrJMNNCK6xNPZh5CDfPLMVQssDhSHuz2Iyv+wPB2tVrY1mKVm124BNyMxxEgt66oA)

That is easy for the compiler, since each function call performs exactly one property lookup.

---

If you find messing with `this` and `bind` to be a bit weird, you could change it to a regular `class` and change function calls to method calls, like this:

```
type ObjStrKey<T> = T extends object ? Extract<keyof T, string> : never;

class Keychain<T> {
  static make<T>() {
    return new Keychain<T>("");
  }
  private constructor(public value: string) {}
  k<K extends ObjStrKey<T>>(k: K): Keychain<T[K]> {
    const value = (this.value ? this.value + "." : "") + k;
    return new Keychain<T[K]>(value);
  }
}
```

which is a little different:

```
const kcp = Keychain.make<Person>();
console.log(kcp.k("child").k("spouse").k("child").k("parent").k("name").value);
// child.spouse.child.parent.name
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwMrAE4GkIgDwBUB8UAvFLlBAB7AQB2AJgM5QD2iEAxsFAPxQCiVVAENO2ANZZmAM1IAaKAzQBLGgHNCALig0IANwioA3AChj7ADZCGTTCHYALISryEA3sagLgQ4EvZQAWyEJFwAKAEood09PVAhgAFdUGm0IAHcoWwcnGjCAIjzwk08AXw8oMFQlXR9odmYaRVQEzmZUULAEuHM-KBrzBIgtJpVVSNcyzzFsdHIqWkZYRBQMLBd8ULEtdHDtrGznXABtdABdN3LPesaufsHiKFDgeyUGADo76F5n14+hAegAGooHk3nkoFoCpFgWJijE4olkqkMllHIcTudQp8iuUymVjCpqKgpCJoAAFAwMBpRcpgIRxGjALQU1BUmhwhxKcx0ZmUhpwhhgZgJBhDKAstlwmhCAJikZqExla6KKBidhgB6onJvIIhCUNDY45XMcwQN7mZiqTbqt5iUJ5Tncwq2+2C4Wi512h0vJ3hF15OkM4Ce+3S2XO7EmAD0UagjrobzdIrN8begdowDeYYgxiAA)

---

Anyway, just an idea.  Hope it helps; good luck!